# Unix: Read file line by line conditionally

Tags: unix, awk

I have a file,

```
aaaa
bbbb,cccc
dddd
eeee,ffff
gggg,hhhh
iiii,jjjj
kkkk
```

My output should be,

```
aaaa
dddd
kkkk
```

that is only with one fields in the record... field seperator is **","**.

I tried,

```
vi test.awk

BEGIN { FS = "[,]+" }

{
    if (NF==1) {
        key = $0
} print 
}
awk -f test.awk source
```

But not working. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work

```
awk -F',' '(NF==1){print $0}' input_file
```

Set the record separator to comma with the `-F` flag and then only print the whole line `$0` when the number of fields `NF` equals 1

Or in short as pointed out by @nu11p01n73R

```
awk -F, 'NF==1'
```

Comment: A shorter version would be  `awk -F, 'NF==1'`

Answer (score 2):

Just skip the lines which has a comma.

```
awk '!/,/' file
```

Comment: didnt work on my version of unix(solaris). but might work for red hat.. anyway thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

`grep` would be sufficient:

```
fgrep -v , file
```

Output:

```
aaaa
dddd
kkkk
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this short `sed` too:

```
sed '/,/d' file
aaaa
dddd
kkkk
```

It delete all lines with `,`